# Как узнать унаследован ли от интерфейса MonoScript Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть код для проверки `MonoBehaviour`.

```
private void CheckMonoBehaviour(SerializedProperty property, Type targetType)
    {
        MonoBehaviour field = property.objectReferenceValue as MonoBehaviour;
        Type fieldType = field.GetType();
        if (targetType.IsAssignableFrom(fieldType) == false)
        {
            property.objectReferenceValue = null;
            Debug.LogError("MonoBehaviour must implement " + targetType + " interface");
        }
    }
```

Я решил использовать этот код для `MonoScript`. Но он стал проходить через `if` даже если я знал что этот скрипт наследуется от нужного интерфейса. В дебаге я увидел, что когда я использую `MonoBehaviour` то `Type` у меня был `{Gun}`(Класс который наследуется от нужного мне интерфейса), а в `MonoScript` у меня было `{UnityEditor.MonoScript}`. Объясните пожалуйста как это происходит и как это решить.

Answer (score 0):

Из учебного проекта **Karting Microgame**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// An attribute that forces a public field to implement an interface.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public sealed class RequireInterfaceAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public readonly Type type;

    public RequireInterfaceAttribute(Type value)
    {
        if (!value.IsInterface)
        {
            throw new Exception("Type must be an interface!");
        }
        type = value;
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;

/// <summary>
/// A drawer for an attribute that forces a public field to implement an interface.
/// </summary>
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof (RequireInterfaceAttribute))]
sealed class RequireInterfaceAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference)
        {
            Debug.LogError("RequireInterfaceAttribute can only be used on fields of type UnityEngine.Object or one of its subclasses!");
            return;
        }
        
        Object propertyObject = property.objectReferenceValue;
        if (propertyObject != null)
        {
            Type interfaceType = ((RequireInterfaceAttribute)attribute).type;
            Type propertyType = propertyObject.GetType ();
            
            if (propertyType.IsAssignableFrom (interfaceType))
            {
                Debug.LogError (propertyObject + " does not implement  " + interfaceType.Name);
                property.objectReferenceValue = null;
            }
        }
        
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label);

        if (property.objectReferenceValue is GameObject)
            property.objectReferenceValue = ((GameObject)property.objectReferenceValue).GetComponent (((RequireInterfaceAttribute)attribute).type);
    }
}
```